# Is it possible to add description in time series insight for user friendly charts

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

In my use case, I have machine codes as 10744/0, and that represents let's say temperature. Is it possible in TSI such that 10744/0 would be mapped to temperature for user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajat,

I'm a PM on the Time Series Insights engineering team.  In short, you can.

Using the Time Series Insights explorer, you can add a label next to the color picker that will persist into the chart description.  It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's close.  I mimicked what I think you want to do in the image below.  Note the measure is temperature and the description is 10744/0.

[TSI Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7MQS.jpg)

If you need more control, you can always integrate TSI into your own web app using our JavaScript Control library.  More on that here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/tutorial-explore-js-client-lib

Hope this helps!

Andrew